# Assigning Property From One Controller to Another Gives Error

Tags: ios, unrecognized-selector

There are so many cases for "Unrecognized Selector Sent To Instance", I don't think I will find mine in so many threads. Or if I do it will take a month or so.

To be short. I receive this error, and my situation is:

I have a table view displaying recipes that are fetched from Core Data. When segue fires, it gets destination controller (which is UITabBarController), and provides a recipe for it.

The code for the segue method is:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"RecipeTabBarController"]) {
    RecipeTabBarController *VC = segue.destinationViewController;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    Recipe *recipe = (Recipe*)[_controller objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    VC.recipe = recipe;
}
```

TabBarController (which is the VC) has a property of a recipe, like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Recipe *recipe;
```

When I tap the cell, the segue fires, and the error occurs, with the following message from console:

**2013-09-25 18:55:21.888 RecipeBank [974:60b] -[UITabBarController setRecipe:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15da8280
2013-09-25 18:55:21.892 RecipeBank [974:60b]**  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBarController setRecipe:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15da8280'
 **First throw call stack:
(0x30583f53 0x3abec6af 0x305878e7 0x305861d3 0x304d5598 0x6676f 0x3319f6f1 0x665b7 0x32e1232b 0x32ec5253 0x32d75971 0x32ced473 0x3054f1d5 0x3054cb79 0x3054cebb 0x304b7ce7 0x304b7acb 0x35185283 0x32d59a41 0x67711 0x3b0f4ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**

RecipeTabBarController imports Recipe class in header and TableViewController that's performing segue imports RecipeTabBarController for it as well. So no mistake there.

What could be wrong?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Wait- you have a tab bar controller IN a navigation controller? I think navigation is supposed to be in tab bar, unless you are sure what you are doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the class of the destination view controller is `UITabBarController` and not your own class `RecipeTabBarController`.  Look in your storyboard as to how you have the segue set up and figure out why things are not what you expect.

Comment: Shoot. That was it. Thank you (:

Comment: Which is exactly what the error message was saying, which most of the other "hits" on the message would have explained.